# Python trouble importing modules

Tags: python, filesystems, module

I am building a web app with this directory structure:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    config/
        __init__.py
        db_config.py
    models/
        __init__.py
        model.py
        datasources/
            __init__.py
            database.py
    ...
    ...
```

Every __init__.py file has

```
__all__ = ['', '', ...]
```

in it, listing the .py files that are in the same directory as it.  So, app/__init__.py is empty, app/config/__init__.py has

```
__all__ = ['db_config']
```

, etc.  in app/models/datasources/database.py, I cannot seem to import anything from app/config/db_config.py.  I have tried

```
import app.config.db_config
import config.db_config
from app.config.db_config import *
```

but none of them has worked.  If anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate hearing them.

Also, I apologize if this is a duplicate question, but I wasn't sure exactly what to search for.

Comment: what does your `sys.path` tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import app.config.db_config` is the best way (avoid non-absolute imports and never ever use import *), and for this to work the `app` directory should be in `sys.path`. If it is not, add the directory to you `PYTHONPATH` or move the project to somewhere this is the case.